# Placing custom markers in google maps from my own system

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

I´m developing a system where the users are going to input some informations about a specific place, such as images, description and geolocation so then I can get the information and create a report.

What I would like to do is to get these information from my system, specially the geolocation and insert the markers in a custom map in my google account (my places). I know that is possible to show a custom map inside my system with the marks, but I dont want to do this.
Nowadays I get the geolocation then I go to my google account and MANUALLY add a marker with the information in the map (https://maps.google.com.br/maps/ms?msid=205818408978727034882.0004e516df27df16c97a2&msa=0&ll=-5.871843,-35.138741&spn=0.318981,0.528374).

I don´t know if my question is clear, but in fact I would like to retrive this information from my system and insert then automatically into my google account in order to show this map in some preparation meetings.

Thanks in advance, I´m looking forward for an answer!!

Comment: Not clear at all what you want.

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear. Are you expecting the users to provide all the information and store that in the backend server side implementation (App Engine). And then do you want to retrieve that information via a REST service or something and plot it dynamically?

Comment: "go to my google account" - this doesn't sound like a programmer's question but rather like some google webapp user question. Flagged for migration to webapps.SE

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the data out of your system in a supported format, such as KML or GeoRSS, you can use a [KML Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) on the Maps API to render the data.

Alternatively, if you don't have loads of data, you may be able to host it in [Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html#fusiontables) and use a [Fusion Tables Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables).  Or if you do have loads of data, you could use [Maps Engine](http://mapsengine.google.com/map/) and a [Maps Engine Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers).